# $f(n) = O(n) \overset ? \implies \log(f(n)) = O(\log n)$

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I have been trying to find a counter-example to prove this is false. However, I feel that I am going in the wrong direction (all logs. are assumed to be in base $2$.)   $$f(n) = O(n) \overset ? \implies \lg(f(n)) = O(\lg n).$$   This is my work so far to tackle this:
\begin{align}
0 &\leq \log(f(n)) \leq c \cdot \log(n)  \\
0 &\leq f(n) \leq n^c
\end{align}

It looks to me that this would always be true (when $f(n)$ is increasing and positive.) But I still don't know where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it the other way.

If:
$$0 \le f(n) \le c n$$

Then, since $\ln$ is a monotone increasing function, hence for sufficiently large $f(n)$:
$$0 \le \ln{(f(n))} \le \ln{(cn)} = \ln{c} + \ln{n}$$

Since $\ln{c}$ is a constant, clearly we have $\ln{(f(n)})$ in $O(\ln n)$.

Comment: $0\le x$ does not imply $0\le \ln x$.

Comment: Luckily $f(n)$ is increasing and positive, so I don't think the statement is incorrect. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm just curious; how did you know to work this way (straight from the condition)? I am new to this field and wouldn't have noticed that myself.

Comment: When trying to show an if-then relationship, the most common ways of proving are to a) start from the condition (direct proof) or b) start by assuming the consequent is false (contradiction proof).

Answer (score 0):

Better to work straightforward from the given conditions:

$0 \le f(n) \le c * n$ implies $\log{(f(n))} \le \log{(c * n)} = \log({c}) + \log({n}) \leq c * \log({n})$

Therefore, $\log(f(n)) = O(\log({n}))$ by using the same $c$ constant

Comment: $0\le f(n)$ does not imply $0\le\log(f(n))$.